# MERN contact form showing undefined values on the backend. Using sendgrid for email

Tags: reactjs, forms, axios, sendgrid, contact-form

I have a contact form in my application (tech stack MERN) and the form sends the data perfectly fine and it hits the route. But on the backend the req shows as undefined. I am using sendgrid to send myself the email, and it sends the email successfully but the message, name, etc are undefined.

This is my form:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import ContactService from '../services/contact.service';
import {
  Button,
  FormControl,
  Container,
  CircularProgress,
  OutlinedInput,
  Paper,
  TextField,
  InputAdornment,
  Box,
  Typography,
  ImageList,
  ImageListItem,
} from "@mui/material";


const ContactForm = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    message: '',
  });
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData((prev) => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
    console.log(formData)
  };

  async function handleSubmit(e, from='/') {
    e.preventDefault();
    const contactForm = new FormData();

    contactForm.append("name", formData.name);
    contactForm.append("message", formData.message);
    contactForm.append("email", formData.email);
    await ContactService.contact(contactForm);
    navigate(from, {
      state: {
        type: "success",
        message: `Message sent!`,
      },
      replace: true,
    });
  };


    return (
        <>
     <div class="flex justify-center items-center w-screen h-screen bg-white">

    <div class="container mx-auto my-4 px-4 lg:px-20">

        <div class="w-full p-8 my-4 md:px-12 lg:w-9/12 lg:pl-20 lg:pr-40 mr-auto rounded-2xl shadow-2xl">
            <div class="flex">
                <h1 class="font-bold uppercase text-5xl">Send us a <br /> message</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-5 md:grid-cols-2 mt-5">
                <input class="w-full bg-gray-100 text-gray-900 mt-2 p-3 rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            type="text" placeholder="First Name*" name='name' onChange={handleChange}/>
                <input class="w-full bg-gray-100 text-gray-900 mt-2 p-3 rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            type="email" placeholder="Email*" name='email' onChange={handleChange}/>
                <input class="w-full bg-gray-100 text-gray-900 mt-2 p-3 rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            type="number" placeholder="Phone*" />
        </div>
                <div class="my-4">
                    <textarea name='message' onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Message*" class="w-full h-32 bg-gray-100 text-gray-900 mt-2 p-3 rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="my-2 w-1/2 lg:w-1/4">
                    <button onClick={handleSubmit} class="uppercase text-sm font-bold tracking-wide bg-blue-900 text-gray-100 p-3 rounded-lg w-full 
                      focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
            Send Message
          </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div
                class="w-full lg:-mt-96 lg:w-2/6 px-8 py-12 ml-auto bg-blue-900 rounded-2xl">
                <div class="flex flex-col text-white">
                    <h1 class="font-bold uppercase text-4xl my-4">Drop in our office</h1>
                    <p class="text-gray-400">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam
                        tincidunt arcu diam,
                        eu feugiat felis fermentum id. Curabitur vitae nibh viverra, auctor turpis sed, scelerisque ex.
                    </p>

                    <div class="flex my-4 w-2/3 lg:w-1/2">
                        <div class="flex flex-col">
                            <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt pt-2 pr-2" />
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col">
              <h2 class="text-2xl">Main Office</h2>
              <p class="text-gray-400">5555 Tailwind RD, Pleasant Grove, UT 73533</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="flex my-4 w-2/3 lg:w-1/2">
            <div class="flex flex-col">
              <i class="fas fa-phone-alt pt-2 pr-2" />
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col">
              <h2 class="text-2xl">Call Us</h2>
              <p class="text-gray-400">Tel: xxx-xxx-xxx</p>
              <p class="text-gray-400">Fax: xxx-xxx-xxx</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="flex my-4 w-2/3 lg:w-1/2">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ENLIGHTENEERING/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" class="rounded-full bg-white h-8 w-8 inline-block mx-1 text-center pt-1">
              <i class="fab fa-facebook-f text-blue-900" />
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/enlighteneering-inc-" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" class="rounded-full bg-white h-8 w-8 inline-block mx-1 text-center pt-1">
              <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in text-blue-900" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>


<div class="flex items-end justify-end fixed bottom-0 right-0 mb-4 mr-4 z-10">
  <div>
    <a title="Buy me a pizza" href="https://www.buymeacoffee.com/Dekartmc" target="_blank" class="block w-16 h-16 rounded-full transition-all shadow hover:shadow-lg transform hover:scale-110 hover:rotate-12">
      <img class="object-cover object-center w-full h-full rounded-full" src="https://img.icons8.com/emoji/48/000000/pizza-emoji.png"/>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
        </>
    )
}

export default ContactForm
```

This is my service:

```
import http from "../utils/http-common";

class ContactService {
    contact(formData) {
        return http.post("/contact", formData);
      }

  
}

export default new ContactService();
```

And my http-common:

```
import axios from "axios";

var url;
process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
  ? (url = "")
  : (url = "http://localhost:5000");
export default axios.create({
    baseURL: url,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    withCredentials: true,
});
```

Finally this is the route that is being successfully hit:

```
module.exports.contact = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, name, message } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body,
        req.params)
   
    const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
    sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
    const msg = {
      to: 'test@example.com', // Change to your recipient
      from: 'test@example.com', // Change to your verified sender
      subject: `${email}`,
      text: `${message}`,
      html: `<p>${message}</p>`,
    }
    sgMail
      .send(msg)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Email sent')
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
      })
}
```

I tried using a different form style, sending the request directly using axios without the service, logging the request to diagnose the problem (the data is 100% sent properly from the frontend).